# Create and Delete input type text if the selected input type checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, input

I have a problem, I need to create or delete as appropriate, a Input type text if a Input type checkbox is selected.

At the moment I can only create the input text, but I manage to find the solution to clear if the checkbox is unchecked.

My HTML code:

```
<form role="form" action="" method="POST">
  <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="category[]" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="category[]" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="category[]" value="3">
  <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="category[]" value="4">
  <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="category[]" value="5">
  <div class="inputCreate"></div>
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Send yours categories">
</form>
```

And the jQuery code is as follows

```
     var wrapper = $(".inputCreate");

$('.myCheckBox').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $(wrapper).append('<input type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="">');
    }
});
```

As I can do that by unchecking the checkbox, also delete the input text field ?.

Solution to this problem:

```
var wrapper = $(".inputCreate");
$(".myCheckBox").change( function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
         $(wrapper).append('<input type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="">');
    }
    else{
        $('.inputCreate :last-child').remove();
    }
});
```

Greeting From Chile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be exactly what you want:
[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/prashant_ghimire/3wdxo1ds/2/)

```
var wrapper = $(".inputCreate");
$(".myCheckBox").change( function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
         $(wrapper).append('<input type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="'+$(this).val()+'">');
    }
    else{
        $('.inputCreate :last-child').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much friend, is exactly what we wanted to achieve. Thanks again. Greetings from Chile.

Comment: Vote and check please!! ;)

Comment: I joined the site a few minutes ago, I get the message that I need +15 reputation hehe. Sorry for not being able to return your valuable help.

Comment: Lol np, I was just saying. Stackoverflow is all about helping. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I assume you want to remove the text box if checkbox unchecked.

```
$('.myCheckBox').click(function() { 
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) { 
         $(wrapper).append('<input type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="">'); 
     }else{ 
         $(wrapper).find('input').remove();
     }
 });
```

Comment: It works, but when re-select any checkbox, this does not create the text field.

Comment: Not working, the console returns me the following error: ReferenceError: input is not defined. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Sorry missed colons. Just try with the edited answer.

Comment: It works, but if I have multiple selected checkboxes and unchecking only one, I erase all input text fields :(. Thanks again for your help.